# PHP: mysql_ping - auto reconnect problem

Tags: php, mysql, ping, reconnect

I'm working with an old but very complex piece of php code, which relies on direct mysql access via mysql_* functions. The code uses mysql_ping extensively, but it assumes each mysql_ping call will also reconnect in case it finds out connection timed out.
The problem is that since MySQL 5.0.*something* mysql_ping **doesn't reconnect automatically**. In the doc's I found I need to call mysql_options with appropriate flag, but **there's no** such function as **mysql_options**. Instead, there's mysqli_options but we literally can't switch to mysqli_* now, it'd take way too much time.
Downgrading MySQL is also not considered as a solution.
Any ideas how to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Upon checking the php manual i found this piece of code that may help you handle the db connection status:

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass');
mysql_select_db('db',$conn);

if (!mysql_ping ($conn)) {
//here is the major trick, you have to close the connection (even though its not currently working) for it to recreate properly.
   mysql_close($conn);
   $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass');
   mysql_select_db('db',$conn);
}

//run queries knowing that your connection is alive....

?>
```

Comment: That explains a lot, thanks! I have been having this same problem too.

Comment: thanks, but I'm looking to find rather a solution to revert behavior of mysql_ping. Code is very complex and I'd like to avoid changing it everywhere.

Comment: @migajek : well good luck with that, though i do not think you will be able to revert the functionality of this single function so easilty. if you will decide to use this solution anyway, a simple seaerch/replace in your code will work for changing all the instances of `mysql_ping` to the above code.